# How do I merge these two dataframes, while keeping the index of my original Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is dataframe1 as df1:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng93s.png]

This is dataframe2 as df2:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hV37.png]

df1 is ordered by Id, I want to add to df1 under FrequencyUsers df2's decimal percentages, but sorted by Id.
So it would look like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p38aO.png]

The decimal numbers are pandas's .value_counts(normalize=True), where you have the frequency of the ProductID over total unique Products.

How would I append df2 to df1?

Another example:
df1 is

```
df1:
    revenue      MaxTemp
   385.943800      14
  1074.160340      9
  2980.857860      8
  1919.723960      10
   385.943800      14
   869.071070      11
   760.289260      13
  1919.723960      10
  2273.413250      7
  2273.413250      7
  1074.160340      9
```

```
df2:
      CET    MaxTemp  MeanTemp MinTemp  MaxHumidity  MeanHumidity  MinHumidity
0  2016-11-17   11      9        7            100           85             63
1  2016-11-18   9       6        3             93           83             66
2  2016-11-19   8       6        4             93           87             76
3  2016-11-20   10      7        4             93           84             81
4  2016-11-21   14     10        7            100           89             77
5  2016-11-22   13     10        7             93           79             63
6  2016-11-23   11      8        5            100           91             82
7  2016-11-24   9       7        4             93           80             66
8  2016-11-25   7       4        1             87           74             57
9  2016-11-26   7       3       -1            100           88             61
10 2016-11-27  10       7        4            100           81             66
```

How would I append to make df3:

```
df3:
      CET    MaxTemp  revenue(shortened)
0  2016-11-17   11        869
1  2016-11-18   9         1074
2  2016-11-19   8         2980
3  2016-11-20   10        1919.723960
4  2016-11-21   14        385.943800
5  2016-11-22   13        760.289260
6  2016-11-23   11        869.071070
7  2016-11-24   9         1074
8  2016-11-25   7         2273.413250
9  2016-11-26   7         2273.413250
10 2016-11-27  10         1919.723960
```

Comment: In your second case, you seem to want to merge base upon MaxTemp which is repeated a different number of times in the two dataframes.  For instance value 11 is only once in df1 but twice in df2.  Considering this, how are you associating the value 869.071070 for both 2016-11-17 and 2016-11-23?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather from your question is, you want to combine df1 and df2 based on MaxTemp column. Here is what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['MaxTemp']) 
df3 = df3[['CET', 'MaxTemp', 'revenue']]
```